# How do I perform meta-analysis of interaction terms?

Tags: interaction, meta-analysis

I recently performed a meta-analysis of survival incidence rate ratio (IRR) in open vs minimally invasive surgery across 3 patient risk sub-groups (Risk score 1, 2 and 3) and calculated the p-for interaction between the sub-groups. The hypothesis was that the risk groups do not really differ in terms of outcomes as p-value for subgroup interaction was 0.74.

The study was well-received by the reviewers but they said that the method was not appropriate and that we should calculate the interaction terms for each study and then meta-analyze them across the studies to determine if the risk score is an effect modifier or not.

I am not sure about how to proceed with this please advise. My data is in the form of n of control and treatment arm, n of events in control and treatment arm, duration of follow-up

Thank you.

Comment: Do they mean conduct a meta-regression with the variable being the risk score? You'll need at least 10 included studies to do this properly.

Comment: I would extract the IRR in subgroup 1 of study A (call it IRR1A), in subgroup 2 of study A, and then in subgroup 3 of study A, then create interaction logIRR (ie logIRR2A vs logIRRA, logIRR3A vs logIRR1A, and also logIRR3A vs logIRR2A). Then I would do the same fo studies B, C, D, etc. Finally, I would use the meta R package (but Stata is fine as well) to meta-analyze these results.

Comment: @Joe_74, this is extremely helpful and answered my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have data from each study for each risk group? It seems that you might need to consider multi-level meta-analysis to take account of that.